# Is MySQL locking innodb rows for the runtime of a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, timeout, deadlock

currently we are experiencing some issues with deadlocks of our database which seem to occur only from time to time. Since we are using innodb as storage engine I am pretty sure its not a problem of table locking.

After taking a look at the show engine innodb status output and the entries in the "latest detected deadlock" section i could nail the problems down to two transactions where one of them is a stored procedure that gets called and takes quite a while to finish. Output is as follows:

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
140114 11:06:27
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 6FACD8E8B, ACTIVE 17 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 5, locked 5
LOCK WAIT 264 lock struct(s), heap size 31160, 780 row lock(s), undo log entries 109
MySQL thread id 54036059, OS thread handle 0x7fa10b40d700, query id 47922176042 10.0.0.1 dbuser Sending data
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT 
  i.invoice_date,
  i.invoice_nr,
  il.item_nr_int,
  il.products_id,
  il.products_variations_id,
  i.shop_id,
  il.costs... // select with multiple joins to gather information to be written in table
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 11172 page no 1017 n bits 120 index `PRIMARY` of table `database`.`products_variations` trx id 6FACD8E8B lock mode S locks rec but not gap waiting
*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 6FACD7D02, ACTIVE 20 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
1078 lock struct(s), heap size 162232, 1918 row lock(s), undo log entries 424
MySQL thread id 54036101, OS thread handle 0x7fa10ba8f700, query id 47922369791 10.0.0.1 dbuser Updating
UPDATE products_variations
    SET availability =  NAME_CONST('availabilityValue',1)
    WHERE products_variations_id =  NAME_CONST('var_products_variations_id',100)
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 11172 page no 1017 n bits 120 index `PRIMARY` of table `database`.`products_variations` trx id 6FACD7D02 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 11172 page no 16837 n bits 128 index `PRIMARY` of table `database`.`products_variations` trx id 6FACD7D02 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

The second transaction shows a query that is called from within the procedure defined below (inside the "update_some_other_data()"):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `update_loads_of_data`() NOT DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER BEGIN
DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE singleid INT;

DECLARE cur_ids CURSOR
FOR

// This query usually contains some JOINS/conditions that make it run for 2-9 seconds
SELECT t1.data_id FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.some_condition = 1;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done = 1;

OPEN cur_ids;

REPEAT
        FETCH cur_ids INTO singleid;

    // here we call another procedure which changes so more data depending on the ids from above
    // takes a while too
        CALL update_some_other_data(singleid);
UNTIL done 
END REPEAT;

CLOSE cur_ids;
END
```

This procedure gets called via a php script and might take around 30-50s to run due to lots of data being updated.

Inside the procedure is a call to another one which also updates loads of stuff, thats the reason why it takes that long.

We do not start a transaction explicitly, neither when calling the procedure above, nor in the other procedure(s) called from within.

My question now is:
Is there a chance that these calls lock lots of rows in my table1 for the whole running time of the procedure so that another process trying to get data from that table might get lock wait timeouts?

what could be a solution to reduce locking time when using this mechanism?

could this also be the reason for a deadlock when we use the same table in 2 processes?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Lock wait timeouts are different than deadlocks. If a deadlock occurs, it's detected and the queries are aborted immediately (no wait required). Please show both the queries that caused the deadlock and/or the full deadlock report. Read locks don't deadlock, so there are going to be some write locks involved.